# dplyr group_by summarise inconsistent number of rows

Tags: r, dplyr

I have been following the tutorial on [DataCamp](https://campus.datacamp.com/courses/dplyr-data-manipulation-r-tutorial). I have the following line of code, that when I run it produces a different value for "drows"

```
hflights %>% 
group_by(UniqueCarrier, Dest) %>% 
summarise(rows= n(), drows = n_distinct(rows))
```

First time:

```
Source: local data frame [234 x 4]
Groups: UniqueCarrier [?]

        UniqueCarrier  Dest  rows drows
                <chr> <chr> <int> <int>
1             AirTran   ATL   211    86
2             AirTran   BKG    14     6
3              Alaska   SEA    32    18
4            American   DFW   186    74
5            American   MIA   129    57
6      American_Eagle   DFW   234   101
7      American_Eagle   LAX    74    34
8      American_Eagle   ORD   133    56
9  Atlantic_Southeast   ATL    64    28
10 Atlantic_Southeast   CVG     1     1
# ... with 224 more rows
```

Second time:

```
   Source: local data frame [234 x 4]
Groups: UniqueCarrier [?]

        UniqueCarrier  Dest  rows drows
                <chr> <chr> <int> <int>
1             AirTran   ATL   211   125
2             AirTran   BKG    14    13
3              Alaska   SEA    32    29
4            American   DFW   186   118
5            American   MIA   129    76
6      American_Eagle   DFW   234   143
7      American_Eagle   LAX    74    47
8      American_Eagle   ORD   133    85
9  Atlantic_Southeast   ATL    64    44
10 Atlantic_Southeast   CVG     1     1
# ... with 224 more rows
```

Third time:

```
Source: local data frame [234 x 4]
Groups: UniqueCarrier [?]

        UniqueCarrier  Dest  rows drows
                <chr> <chr> <int> <int>
1             AirTran   ATL   211    88
2             AirTran   BKG    14     7
3              Alaska   SEA    32    16
4            American   DFW   186    79
5            American   MIA   129    61
6      American_Eagle   DFW   234    95
7      American_Eagle   LAX    74    31
8      American_Eagle   ORD   133    67
9  Atlantic_Southeast   ATL    64    31
10 Atlantic_Southeast   CVG     1     1
# ... with 224 more rows
```

My question is why does this value constantly change? What is it doing?

Comment: `drows = n_distinct(rows)` should be equal to 1 all the time here. I dont get whats wrong

Comment: also its funny we have the same login

Comment: Possibly a bug with their online shell? it is kind of funny we have the same login, what are odds of commenting on the the same question.

Comment: `hflights` is a package on CRAN. I just downloaded the package and tested your code. It shows the same issue.

Comment: same thing for me. and then it crashed my rstudio.

Comment: The docs say `This is a faster and more concise equivalent of length(unique(x))`. Subbing that in gives you `1` for every observation. So something up with `n_distinct`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently this is normal behaviour, see this issue here. https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/issues/2222.

> This is because values in list columns are compared by reference, so
>   n_distinct() treats them as different unless they really point to the
>   same object:

So the internal storage of the df changes the way the thing works. Hadley's comment in that issue seems to say it might be a bug (in the sense of unwanted behaviour), or it might be expected behaviour they need to document better.

Comment: Ok, that explains why the result is not 1. I still don't understand why the values vary each time I run the command.

Comment: idk. I got too deep into this and found some stuff I don't understand.

Comment: If I call it directly (like you did), it's screws up. If I wrap it in a function (like `f <- function(x) { n_distinct(x) }`, then call that inside the `summarise`, it's fine. If I call `drows = n_distinct(c(rows))`, it works. I don't understand why, other than changing the way you address `rows` changes the internal representation of the data, which makes one way work and another way fail.

Comment: Also doing `mtcars %>% summarise(n = n(), drows = n_distinct(n()))` gives the correct answer (`drows = 1`). And using `mutate` instead is also fine, `mtcars %>% summarise(n = n(), drows = n_distinct(n))`. But `summarise` and `n_distinct` along with re-using the created variable inside the `summarise`, that screws it up. (Also fails if you use functions other than `n()`.)  I give up.